# Finding highest decimals and rounding up with VBA - version numbering

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing code at the moment which is required look through a column of decimals, find the highest one, set destination cells based on the highest decimal and then round up that decimal to the nearest integer. This is to automate version numbering on a master data spreadsheet i.e. if the code finds 0.03 is the latest version in the archive, it will need to write the current data below it in the archive as 0.04 and set the version number on the main page as 1 (status "draft").

The data is being inputted via userforms but for testing purposes I am setting values within the code. The data will be written to a sheet with a version number in column I with the header "Version No." and a SKU code in column A. The value in the SKU column should be "test" and the version numbers should be 0.01, 0.02 etc. The code is required to find the highest version number in column I and then check if the SKU matches the one entered (in the final version all worksheets will be locked so the end user will be unable to enter data directly in the cells).

I found a link to [a worksheet function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746905/rounding-up-to-nearest-higher-integer-in-vba) but found myself with a compile error so I am unsure if this function is compatible with the method I am using.

This is what I have so far.

```
   Sub SetArchiveValues()

Dim FoundArchive As Boolean
Dim VersionNumber As Single
Dim dSKU As String
Dim SKUArchiveDestination As String
Dim VersionArchive As Single
Dim VersionNumberArchiveDestination As String

FoundArchive = True
VersionNumber = 1
dSKU = test

'if archive exists, set values and cell references
If FoundArchive = True Then
    For Each cell3 In Worksheets("Coding and Label Archive").Columns("I").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        'tell code to ignore header
        If cell3.Value <> "Version No." Then
                If VersionNumber = Int(cell3.Value) Then
                    'find latest version number
                        If cell3.Value > CurrentValue And cell.Offset(0, -8).Value = dSKU Then
                            SKUArchiveDestination = cell3.Offset(1, -8).Address
                            VersionArchive = cell3.Offset(0, 0).Value
                            VersionNumberArchiveDestination = cell3.Offset(1, 0).Address
                            CurrentValue = cell3.Value
                            Debug.Print "Current Value = " & CurrentValue
                            Debug.Print "Cell3.value =" & cell3.Value
                            Debug.Print "SKU Archive Destination = " & SKUArchiveDestination
                            Debug.Print "Version Archive Value = " & VersionArchive
                            Debug.Print "Version Number Archive Destination = " & VersionNumberArchiveDestination
                       End If
                End If
        End If
    Next
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is...

Comment: I don't see where you are rounding anything up in your code.

Comment: Apologies if the question is unclear. The coding loop with "If cell3.value>currentvalue" loops until it finds the latest version number in a column, but I am struggling to get it to work if the version is 0.01, 0.02 etc.The code sees Int(cell3.value) as 0 if the cell value < 0.5 so I can't find a way to set the main page version number based on the archive version.